# not able to load java script files and bower_components/angular/angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

When i run the localhost:3000 server , i'm getting these errors in the console:

http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost:3000/controller.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

It was working if i put the angular.js script in the index.html instead of putting it seperately in controller.js , i don't know why i'm getting an error when i use script tags.

the directory diagram is like this

```
-files
  -bower_components
    -angular
  -index.html
  -controller.js
  -server.js
```

this is the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
<style>
#list   
{ margin-left:320px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family:verdana;
}
button     
{ color:yellow;background-color:red;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  font-size:40px;
  padding: 14px 32px;
}
button:hover
{ background-color:peachpuff;
  color:tomato;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:cyan;">

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">

<h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:verdana;">To-Do LiSt</h1>

<div style="margin-left:300px">
<input type="text" ng-model="task.name" style="background-color:black;color:white;font-size:40px;width:40%">
<button ng-click="addtask()">Add</button>&nbsp;
<button ng-click="updatetask()">Update</button>&nbsp;<button ng-click="clearfield()">Clear</button>
</div>

<ul>
<li id="list" ng-repeat="task in todolist">
{{task.name}}
<button ng-click="deletetask(task._id)">Delete</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button ng-click="edittask(task._id)">Edit</button>
</li>
</ul>

</div>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>

</html>
```

this is the server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test");

var TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
 name : {type: String, required: true}
 });

var TodoModel = mongoose.model('todolist',TodoSchema);

app.get('/',function(req,res){

    res.sendFile("/index.html",{root:__dirname}); 
});

app.get('/todolist', function (req, res){
    TodoModel.find(function(err,tasks){
      res.json(tasks);
     });
});

app.post('/todolist', function (req, res) {

  TodoModel.create({name:req.body.name},function(err,task){
    res.send('created');
  });

});

app.delete('/todolist/:id', function (req, res) {

 TodoModel.remove({_id:req.params.id}, function (err) {
     res.send('');
 });
});

app.get('/todolist/:id', function (req, res) {

  TodoModel.findById(req.params.id, function (err, task){
    res.json(task);
  });
});

app.put('/todolist/:id', function (req, res) {

  TodoModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
     {name: req.body.name},
      function (err, task) {

      res.json(task);
    }
  );
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server.js file add following lines and check it once.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

in node js you have to set registry for accessing a relative paths.

Comment: thanks man....can u explain why do we need to do that ? , we are giving the path from index.html , so why are we using express.static in server.js

Comment: Accept the the answer if it is helps you buddy..in node js we create our own server so it is not able to under stand the relative path so we have to explicitly specify the current directory as a root directory and based on that server resolve the relative path..

Comment: thanks mate....can u suggest websites where i can strengthen my basics on nodejs ?

Comment: You can use 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/' for understanding the basic stuffs of node js but unfortunately still i can not find a proper content website of node js but as per your problems and for development purpose you can get help from various blogs and internet contents..